# Android: How to add archinamon AspectJ plugin in an android library?

Tags: android, aspectj

I want to track user UI actions(clicks etc) for which I'm using Archinamon AspectJ plugin (since it supports Kotlin too).

When I try to create an library(aar) with the above plugin and integrate it with any app which has UI elements, it does not recognise the UI actions taken by user. However, with directly using the plugin in the project it works fine.

https://github.com/Archinamon/android-gradle-aspectj

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Seconding Nándor's statement, I recommend you to edit your question into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Learning how to ask a question in a smart way in order to dramatically increase the probability of helpful answers is part of the game in any forum, here even more so.

Comment: I have created sample on github with 3 projects and issue is explained in ReadMe.   https://github.com/sheelaknaik/AspectJ    Please help me as I'm struggling with this for a long time.

Comment: Trying to rephrase the question, how to include Archinamon plugin into an aar and use in application?